# How can I take variable from ejs to app.js in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

I'm pretty newbie in node.js and trying to pass JSON data from ejs to app.js
but I don't know how to pass through from ejs to app.js.

What I did was `var stringify1 = <%- JSON.stringify(jsonfile_1) %>;` from  in ejs,

and then after the user clicks save button, let it goes to `'/save'`
Then I used app.get like code below.

```
app.get('/save', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  console.log(stringify1);
});
```

Here is partial code of script from ejs which make json data and then goes to `app.get('/save',..`

```
    <script>
      function save(){
        var jsonfile_1 = {channel: {}};
        for (i = 0; i < jsonfile.channel.length; i++){
          var divData = document.getElementById(jsonfile.channel[i]);
          var mac_tmp = jsonfile.channel[i];
          if(divData.dataset.x != 0 && divData.dataset.y != 0){
            jsonfile_1.channel[mac_tmp] = [divData.dataset.x, divData.dataset.y];
          }
        }
        console.log(jsonfile_1.channel);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonfile_1));
        var stringify1 = <%- JSON.stringify(jsonfile_1) %>;
        saveText(JSON.stringify(jsonfile_1.channel), "hello.json");
      }
    </script>
```

Here is my button code

```
<a onclick= "save()" id="imageSave" href="/save">Save</a>
```

I tried to find in google but couldn't find solutions that I want.

Can anybody have an idea for this?

Thanks in advance.

P.S with above code it gives me an error that jsonfile_1 is undefined.

**EDIT**

```
  <script>
  function save(){
    var jsonfile_1 = {channel: {}};
    for (i = 0; i < jsonfile.channel.length; i++){
      var divData = document.getElementById(jsonfile.channel[i]);
      var mac_tmp = jsonfile.channel[i];
      if(divData.dataset.x != 0 && divData.dataset.y != 0){
        jsonfile_1.channel[mac_tmp] = [divData.dataset.x, divData.dataset.y];
      }
    }
    console.log(jsonfile_1.channel);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonfile_1));
    document.getElementById("jsonjson").value = JSON.stringify(jsonfile_1.channel);
    saveText(JSON.stringify(jsonfile_1.channel), "hello.json");
  }

  function saveText(text, filename){
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-u,'+encodeURIComponent(text));
    a.setAttribute('download', filename);
    a.click()
  }
  </script>
```

save button

```
<li><a onclick= "save()" id="imageSave" href="/save">Save</a></li>
```

app.js

```
app.get('/save', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.json1);
});
```

Comment: In server side, you have req and res object available. So you can use them to get your data. In client side, you may put your data in some hidden div element and try to get them in server using req.body.name , you can search more on how to get req parameter in server..

Comment: Can you provide more code, it's seems to be incomplete and not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve. I believe  the `saveText(JSON.stringify(jsonfile_1.channel), "hello.json");`  makes an Ajax call so you can grab the params like **`req.query.param_name`**

Comment: @SarojSasmal wait let me EDIT

Comment: @SarojSasmal I edited it.. Please help me out here.... :'(

Comment: @SarojSasmal I think your very first comment is the right way.. Can you give me more specifically with the code?? :'(

Comment: @paulc1111 hang on .lets get to the bottom of this .

Comment: @SarojSasmal Thank you so much for helping me out, I actually made `hidden div` and put json data to the `div value`, How can I call from server side? I tried req.body.jsonjson but it doesn't work.
My hidden div is like this `<div id="jsonjson" name="json1" value=""></div>`

Comment: @paulc1111 It should be `req.body.json1`  if you are posting a form or `req.query.json` for Ajax GET. You have to access it by it's `name` not `ID`

Comment: @SarojSasmal Hm.. but it gives me `undefined` from console.log..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138596/discussion-between-saroj-sasmal-and-paulc1111).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to put the json content in a hidden field inside a form and submit the form when saveImage link is clicked.

```
<form action="/save" id="hdnJsonForm" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="json1" id="jsonjson">
</form>
```

In javascript you have to submit the form when the save link is clicked. You can achieve this by if you are using JQuery .

```
$(document).on('click','#imageSave',function(){
    $('#hdnJsonForm').submit();
 });
```

All you need to do next is to change your route to post

```
app.post('/save', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  console.log(stringify1);
});
```

Hope it helps!!